# use where clause to search from a substring SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have column which contains below values:

```
names
-----------------
johnDoeKing
Joseph
MaxSecond
Plank
-----------------
```

Now I have an input string:

```
johnDoeMaxAlexPaul
```

is there a way I can use where clause which will return JohnDoeKing and MaxSecond from my column when I search with this input string in where clause ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `LIKE`:

```
DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(100) = 'johnDoeMaxAlexPaul';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE @InputString LIKE '%' + names + '%';
```

[**Here is a live demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=bad4ce028db9f06dfd067b2168e2e9c6) of this, and the results are:

```
╔═════════╗
║  names  ║
╠═════════╣
║ johnDoe ║
║ Max     ║
╚═════════╝
```

Comment: nope.. here InputString should be at place of names and names should be at place of @InpputString.. And thats the issue.. name is a substring of inputstring

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz yes, and that's what this query is doing, did you try it?

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz well, the question now is completely different and doesn't even explain how many letters should you try to match

Comment: letters are actually not fixed.. It can vary row to row

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz then how could you know which results to match?, this doesn't make sense....I could match `Joseph` because the first 2 letters `Jo` are in `johnDoeMaxAlexPaul`